# Ext JS - How to update data source update every minute with deltas?

Tags: extjs, grid, updates, real-time

Looking for a reference implementation. Haven't tried LiveGrid - though tilting towards that implementation. Before I migrate, I was wondering if anyone could point me in a better direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4392 works for this.